# Poll a URL and return a true when the response contains a string

Tags: android

I'm modifying an app and wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. Basically, I want the app to poll a URL and in the json response, if a value is true, then continue on.

The current code has this:

```
    return  prepareForUpgrade() &&
            uploadImage(firmware) &&
            checkUpgradeStatus() &&
            rebootDevice();
private boolean prepareForUpgrade() {

    Timber.i("Preparing...");
    try {
        Response<ResponseBody> prepare = DeviceRestApi.prepareFirmwareUpgrade(
                Constants.Device.DEFAULT_USERNAME,
                Constants.Device.DEFAULT_PASSWORD,
                DeviceRestApi.COMMAND_PREPARE
        ).execute();
        boolean result = prepare.isSuccessful();
        Timber.i("Result: %s", result);
        return result;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "Preparation failed");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically, the process continues on if the network request was successful, but I want to replace that behavior with something that polls a URL and the URL says when its successful.

Don't need a solution exactly, just wondering which way to go. Should I try a Service? An IntentService? Something else?

Comment: ` that polls a URL and the URL says when its successful.` Would like to know what you intend with that ?

Comment: The response will contain a flag that should tell the App to move on with its flow. Basically the app is telling a device "hey, i'm about to do something" and the device tells the app "ok, i'm ready"